# How to read in all text files from UNIX bash directory in Cloudera's Python API

Tags: python, bash, file-handling

I'm still pretty new to Cloudera and using the UNIX environment. I have written a mapper that reads in .txt files from a directory in my Windows system, which works just fine. I read files in like this:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob("*.txt")
```

Is there an equivalent way to do this in the UNIX environment? I know I can read in one file by

```
infile=sys.stdin
```

but as far as reading all in from one directory I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: The Python should work the same on Windows and Linux. Note, though, that the files may not end in ".txt" as much on a linux box.